# Passing different value to a scope based on where the object gets called

Tags: angularjs

I have two objects where I pass a value to the same scope. Like so:

```
value1 = function () {
  $scope.sectionTitle = 'title1';
};

value2 = function () {
  $scope.sectionTitle = 'title2';
};
```

Then I call `sectionTitle` twice

```
<div ng-show="value1">{{sectionTitle}}</div>
<div ng-show="value2">{{sectionTitle}}</div>
```

I end up getting title2 as the `sectionTitle` on both and want to know how I can get different values based on where the `sectionTitle` gets called?

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be the same scope variable? The easy answer is just to use a different named variable.

Comment: I'm using the same template for the two sections and pass in the `sectionTitle` into the href for each. I do want to cut down on the amount of html pages if possible. This is an easier solution, but was wondering if there's a way to do it where I can pass different values to the same function called in different places

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute directive with a prototype scope and then override the parent scope value inside the directive like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uju68m6k/1/

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('dylan', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.sectionTitle = Math.random();
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div dylan>{{sectionTitle}}</div>
    <div dylan>{{sectionTitle}}</div>
</body>
```

The key here is the `scope: true` setting in the directive, this will create a scope that inherits from the parent scope prototypically